# Best practice for camel + webapp project

Tags: web-applications, apache-camel, job-scheduling

I have a web-app project where i need to use camel. We have two options, 1.) to create a separate web-app project where camel runs, 2.) Run camel in the same web-app project.

Are there any arguments to use different web-app project to deploy camel? Maybe separation of concern's argument? Or is it usual practice to run it in the same web-app project.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what your web application is dealing with. If camel changes are minimal which is testable then yes you can fit camel in existing application, but if the changes and architecture is changing which needs good testing then I always recommend to create a new application.

Please elaborate what application is doing?

Comment: Well, web-app project has mostly API's. I get your point about how it depends on complexity of the web-app project. I guess its a call that all dev's need to make.. either way just wanted to know about best practices. It seems, it can be either way. thanks.